# What's the number of sequences containing $10$ ones and $20$ zeroes that don't have adjacent ones.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> How many sequences containing 10 ones and 20 zeroes don't have adjacent ones?

So I'm kinda lost here. Which way do I go? Do I find all combinations, then subtract the number of sequences that have adjacent ones, that seems like an option, but then I am not quite sure how to find all sequences with adjacent ones.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Arrange the ten ones.  Now put a zero in between each one, leaving you with $20-9=11$ zeroes to place and $11$ slots in which to place them.

Comment: @lulu I am facepalming right now, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome, good luck!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, pretty new here, will do that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is one strategy that would work, but it would get bogged down in the Inclusion-Exclusion principle and would require a lot of calculation to sort out all of the details.  If we think about the problem differently, we can come up with a strategy that avoids that.

As Lulu suggests, imagine putting the ten 1's in a line, and then adding nine of the twenty 0's into the gaps between them.  Now we only have to count the number of ways to put the remaining eleven 0's into those gaps or the ends.  This is a stars-and-bars problem with eleven stars and ten bars, so our answer is just ${21\choose10}=352716$.

Answer (score 3):

Put the $20$ zeros in a line, creating $21$ slots where a one might be placed. Choose $10$ of these slots in ${21\choose10}$ ways.

Comment: /facepalm/ Yup, that's absolutely the better way to think about it.